# Thrust and stiff ODE solvers in odeint

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, odeint

I am studying a parameterized system of **stiff** ODEs and need to solve it for many values of its parameters.  I am working in C/C++/CUDA and I want to solve these systems in parallel.

I was wondering if I could use odeint for this.  I found [this example](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/thrust/lorenz_parameters.cu), but according to [this page](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/overview.html) of the documentation, stiff solvers require ublas types.

Does it mean that their stiff solvers are incompatible with Thrust?

Comment: are you referring to `rosenbrock4` and `Works only with Boost.uBLAS vectors as state types.`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can not use the Rosenbrock method with Thrust.